# Next Privilege overlapping Achievements

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, achievements-dialog, beta-sites

For *beta* sites exclusively, the opened achievements tab will be overlapped by the "Next Privilege" box on a user's own activity page:

[image]

The above was took with Language Learning Stack Exchange open though I have reproduced in:

- Retrocomputing Stack Exchange (beta)
- Coffee Stack Exchange (beta)
- PPCG (beta)

Can we not have the next privilege overlapping the Achievements tab (when opened)?